# jQuery self executing function not fireing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of refactoring my spaghetti jQuery code into components. So far, I've constructed one component, which is encapsulated in a self-fireing function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
});

(function () {
    Component.init();

    var Component = {
        init: function () {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
            debugger;
        },
        cacheDom: function () {
            //Initialize properties
        },
        bindEvents: function () {
            //setup eventhandlers
        },
        function1: function (event) {
            //do some work here
        },
    };
})();
```

My jQuery is hitting the dom.ready function, but my self-executing function is not doing anything. Also, I did try to remove the self-executing function and initialize the component in my `$(document).ready(function)` but it is not hitting the `debugger` that I have put inside the init function..

I have looked through my code multiple times, and can't seem to figure out why the `Component` is not initialized at all.

Comment: Create a fiddle reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this issue by updating your current module pattern like:

```js
// This is our main Component module
//---------------------------------------------------
var Component = (function() {

  // All private variables here
  //---------------------------------------------------
  var $blog;

  // Place initialization logic here
  //---------------------------------------------------
  var init = function() {
    console.log('Inside init()')
    cacheDom();
    bindEvents();
  };
  
  // Cache all required DOM elements here
  //---------------------------------------------------
  var cacheDom = function() {
    //Initialize properties
    console.log('Inside cacheDom()')
    $blog = $('#blog');
  };
  
  // All event handler setup here
  //---------------------------------------------------
  var bindEvents = function() {
    //setup eventhandlers
    console.log('Inside bindEvents()')
    $blog.on('click', function1);  
  };
  
  // All other methods here
  //---------------------------------------------------
  var function1 = function(event) {
    //do some work here
  };

  // Return the methods you want to make public
  //---------------------------------------------------
  return {
    init,
  };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Inside document.ready()')
  Component.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using this module we make sure that `Component.init()` is only called when DOM is fully ready. One more interesting thing about this pattern is that we can now only access the `init()` public method from outside, all other private methods like `cacheDom()`, `bindEvents()` are not accessible from outside. Thus `Component.cacheDom();` will return `undefined`. I think other than `init()` you will not need to make any other method public, as all your logic will be now handled inside the `Component` module.

Comment: That's really nice. However, it seems as if all my events are fired from the start and doesn't do anything afterwards - For example I have this for a bootstrap modal:
`$root.on('show.bs.modal', populateModal(event));`

It works outside the component model, but here it just fires the event once, and doesn't do it afterwards

Comment: That's because you are calling the function itself using `()` and assigning that to the event handler. To resolve that we simply need to wrap it inside function like [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6utjqprg/) or just assign the function without `()` and event will be passed automatically like [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6utjqprg/1/).

Comment: Awesome! Really elaborate answer :-)  I hope that I'm moving in the right direction by employing this pattern on my jQuery spaghetti.

Comment: Also, we also do the same for some of our very old jQuery projects. It helps a lot, as most of them are now in the maintenance phase. Also, if any module get very large based on lines of code, we try to create sub-modules based on similar logic, to keeps things in check and better error tracing & debugging purpose.

Comment: It makes sense. It quickly gets out of hand otherwise!